# How to access my HDFS filesystem from another machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running programme which create hdfs directory and put file into it . In java programme i am using congiuraion like this.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://localhost:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker","localhost:8021");
```

But now my collegue from another machine want to copy the file present in my HDFS.
For That i am sure He has to connect to my HDFS.
So how my collegue can connect to my HDFS and copy file from it.

My collegue using below code to access my HDFS.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://192.168.1.239:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker","192.168.1.239:8021");
```

but it is not working giving following error

```
14/11/03 16:17:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:26 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:27 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:28 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:29 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/11/03 16:17:31 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Call to 192.168.1.239/192.168.1.239:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:124)
    at com.volcareTest.VolcareTest.VolcareApp.main(VolcareApp.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2200(Client.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1093)
    ... 20 more
```

If my collegue approach is wrong then what is the correct answer.

Comment: Check whether the other user is able access your hadoop job tracker UI from console itself

Comment: No. other user is not able to access  192.168.1.239:50070, how he can access it.

Comment: are you both in the same network? Ip range and all ??

Comment: Share contents of your `core-site.xml`. Which version of hadoop you are using by the way ?

Comment: Sorry K S Nidhin,i change my connection some minutes ago. now we are in same network and other user is able to access 192.168.1.239:50070, but the problem is same, how he cann access the hdfs

Comment: Hi blackSmith,this is my system configuration.                                                                                                           <configuration> 
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system. A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.
  </description>
</property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem , I just changed in my core-site.xml configuration file 
instead of localhost:9000, i changed it to 192.168.1.239 for fs.default.name property and same with my java code too , now it works

Answer (score 1):

If both manchines are in same network, then

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://192.168.1.239:9000");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker","192.168.1.239:8021");
```

This must work, If both the machines are in different and then having connected to internet, you can find the public ipaddress of the machine to get connected by [ipaddress finder](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Hope it helps you.